# In javascript, when I convert random number to a string, it is much slower than I expect

Tags: javascript, string, performance, numbers

When I iterate over large number of elements, converting random number to a string Is very  slow. Is there any way to make this faster.

I would expect this code to run In less than 30 ms, but it actually takes more than 2 seconds.

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10_000_000; i++) {
    String(Math.random());
}
```

Comment: What is the basis of your expectation?

Comment: If you want better performance, you can do `Math.random() + ''`

Comment: @PrerakSola or just `Math.random().toString()`

Comment: @asyncawait Performance wise it is almost the same as what OP is doing. https://jsbench.me/u1leqahuw3/1

Comment: @asyncawait I think the point is to avoid an explicit function call.

Comment: If I did String(i) or i.toString()... it is still very slow. Maybe just converting number into string just does hundreds of operations?

Comment: It seems like converting a number to a string is just slow. It probably uses the method of converting with multiple divisions which is kind of slow